# Homework: Sublist? checking if an item is a sublist of the first one

Tags: scheme, racket, atomic, sublist

So I have this program that needs to be written in Scheme using Racket that has the following properties and I am stumped. The function is called `sublist?` with two inputs of `S` and `L` which are both lists. It checks whether S is a sublist of `L` and returns `#t` or `#f`.

Examples would be similar to:

```
sublist? of (A A) and (A B C) is #f
sublist? of (A B C) and (A B D A B C D) is #t
sublist? of (A (B)) and (C ((A (B))) (C)) is #t
```

A small function called `extractLists` needs to be created to extract the lists and `(atomicSublist S L)` is used to check the two extracted lists to see if every element of `S` is in `L`.

So far I have

```
(define (atomicSublist S L)
  (cond ((null? L) #f)
        ((equal? S (car L)) #t)
        (else (atomicSublist S (cdr L)))))
```

The second part does not really do anything and doesn't even output the extracted value of S.

*Updated code:*
Just for testing I use `atomicSublist` to check for now.

Answer (score 1):

Begin with a simpler problem and then generalize.

How would you write a function that checks whether a symbol `'a` is an a list or not?

Comment: Well my initial idea was more along the lines of:

    (define (atomicSublist S L)
    (cond ((null? L) #f)
        ((equal? (car L) S) #t)
        (else(atomicSublist S (cdr L)))
    ))

Comment: That's a good beginning. In the else part, you need to use (or <possibility1> <possibility2> ...) etc. 

Here are some of the possibilities:
    1) L is equal to S.  
    2) S is in (cdr L).

Comment: Tried that, didn't seem to work. Some test cases work but not all of them right now.

Comment: Update your question with the code you have now, and state which test cases work and which doesn't.

Comment: I also can't apply my extractLists to my nested sublist? function either.

Comment: You need some helper functions. Can you write the function is-prefix? which for (is-prefix? s l) returns #t if the list s is a prefix of l. For example (is-prefix? '(a b) '(a b c d)) returns #t.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not too sure what that means, but it is possible to add more functions I guess. Not too sure where I would start though.

Comment: Wait I see now, the atomicSublist is supposed to be used for that, and all of it goes into a function called sublist?

Comment: If you don't know where to start, I recommend taking a look at the list chapter http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-13.html#node_sec_9.4

Comment: Took a quick look, but not too sure how to apply it to get it to work properly.

Comment: Any idea how I could get sublist? working though? because (else (atomicSublist (extractLists(S) extractLists(L)))) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want this check `((equal? S (car L) ) #t)` as the car of L will never be equal to the list S.

Heres what I came up with for atomicSublist.

```
    (define (atomicSublist S L)
        (cond
            [(null? S) #t]
            [(member? (car S) L) (atomicSublist (cdr s) L)]
            [else #f]))
```

Comment: Never mind that part kind of works now but still throws errors when I try to use sublist? and also some of the results are still incorrect.

Comment: Forgot a bracket, sorry, fixed.

Comment: For example (atomicSublist '(A A) '(A B C)) should be false and not pop up true.

Comment: I think I need a nested loop to go through the first list and then the second one.

Comment: extractLists had a missing bracket, so i fixed that. You're going to want to write a function to remove the letter after its been found in L.

Comment: How would I go about deleting items from S or L to do this?

Comment: Also I don't want to strip everything using extractLists because of the way it wants to check for similar sublists.

Comment: (extractLists '((A ((B))) E (B) (A B C))) should give this as output ((A ((B))) (B) (A B C))

Comment: I see that now. Well, you should be able to figure out how to remove an item from a list after its been found. Just create a simple remove first occurence function and then call it on L in the recursive call of the member? clause.

Comment: Also, that makes extracts lists very easy. Just check if each item in the list is a list, and if it is, cons it all together.

Comment: I tried to add ((equal? S (car L)) (cdr L)) this in but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little ambiguous. What should this return? (sublist? '(a (b)) '(a b c d e)) ??

Anyway here is what i wrote:

```
(define (sublist? s l)  
  (cond ((null? s) true)
        ((atom? (car s))
         (cond ((exists? (car s) l) (sublist? (cdr s) (remove-elm (car s) l)))
               (else false)))
        (else 
         (cond ((sublist? (car s) l) (sublist? (cdr s) (remove-elm (car s) l)))
               (else false)))))


(define (exists? elm l)
  (cond ((null? l) false) 
        ((atom? (car l))
         (cond ((symbol=? elm (car l)) true)
               (else (exists? elm (cdr l)))))
        (else
         (cond ((exists? elm (car l)) true)
               (else (exists? elm (cdr l)))))))



(define (remove-elm elm l)
  (cond ((null? l) '())
        ((null? elm) l)
        ((atom? elm)
         (cond ((atom? (car l)) 
                (cond ((symbol=? elm (car l)) (cdr l))
                      (else (cons (car l) (remove-elm elm (cdr l))))))
               (else
                (cons (remove-elm elm (car l)) (remove-elm elm (cdr l))))))
        (else
         (remove-elm (cdr elm) (remove-elm (car elm) l)))))


(define (atom? elm)
  (and (not (null? elm)) (not (pair? elm))))
```

(sublist? '(a a) ('a b c d e)) returns #f.  (sublist? '(a b c) '(a d b e c f)) returns #t.  (sublist? '(a (b)) '(c ((a (b)) e f))) returns #t.  (sublist? '(a (b) b) '(c ((a (b)) e f))) retrns #f.  However, (sublist? '(a (b)) '(a b c d)) returns #t.

Comment: Every time I see this I'm amazed at how you guys can read this stuff ;-)

Comment: True. Probably with practice I will be able to write more legibly. Can you provide a better looking code?