# Need help writing a code check if a list is a sublist of another list?

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket, sublist

I'm working on a program in DrRacket that checks where a list of natural numbers, lst1, is a sublist of another list of natural numbers, lst2.
So far I have,

```
(define (sublist? lst1 lst2)
  (cond
    [(or (not (cons? lst2)) (empty? lst2)) false]
    [(or (equal? lst1 (cons lst2)) (sublist? lst1 (cons lst2))) true]
    [else (sublist? lst1 (cons lst2))]))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822537/homework-sublist-checking-if-an-item-is-a-sublist-of-the-first-one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776363/recursive-sublist-function/28778343#28778343 also

Answer (score 1):

You're using `cons` for everything. In some places you need to replace it with `car` or `first`, and in others with `cdr` or `rest`.

The only purpose of `cons` is to create new cons cells/prepend a new item to a list.